# What should i do guys my process 8080 is not getting killed

Tags: java

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.1052]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Hp>netstat -ano | findstr 8080
  TCP    0.0.0.0:8080           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       5064
  TCP    [::]:8080              [::]:0                 LISTENING       5064

C:\Users\Hp>taskkill /pid 5064/F
ERROR: The process "5064/F" not found.

C:\Users\Hp>taskkill /pid 5064 /F
ERROR: The process with PID 5064 could not be terminated.
Reason: Access is denied.

C:\Users\Hp>
```

Comment: Did you try to kill it as administrator?

Comment: The reason why it is not killed is already stated there: Access denied. Flagged for closing

Answer (score 0):

Please click on the Windows button, write "command" in the search box, right click on the "Command Prompt" application and choose "Run as Administrator" and then try to kill the process again.